# Cantor-set, product topology

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

We provide $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology and view the product space $X:=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}:=\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\{0,1\}$ (the space of every 0-1-sequence), with $0\notin\mathbb{N}$ .

Show that a base of the product topology is constituted by every set of the following form:

$U_{y_1,..., y_n}:=\{x\in X: x_1=y_1,\dotso, x_n=y_n\}\quad (n\in\mathbb{N}, y_1,\dotso, y_n\in\{0,1\})$

Hello,

I want to solve this task.
To show that $U_{y_1,..., y_n}$ is a base, I have to proof, that every set in the product topology is union of elements in $U_{y_1,..., y_n}$.

I have a question about the union of these sets.
For example: When I have the sets $U_{0,0,\dotso, 0}$ and $U_{1,1,\dotso, 1}$, what is $U_{0,0,\dotso, 0}\cup U_{1,1,\dotso, 1}\stackrel{?}{=}U_{1,1,\dotso, 1}$

Actually this task seems trivial to me, since every set $U_{y_1,..., y_n}$ describes a 0-1-sequence. So for every 0-1-sequence we already have a set $U_{y_1,..., y_n}$ which describes it.

Am I wrong?
What do I have to show?
I would be thankful for a hint.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's consider $U_{0,0,...,0}\cup U_{1,1,...,1}$.  The set $U_{0}$ consists of all sequences that begin with a 0.  Similarly, the set $U_1$ consists of all sequences that begin with a 1.  Their union $U_0\cup U_1$ is therefore all sequences that begin with a 0 or 1, i.e., the whole space, but this is not a general phenomenon. Now consider $U_{0,0}\cup U_{1,1}$, which is the set of all sequences beginning with two 0's or two 1's.  So, for example, the sequence $(0,1,0, ...)\not\in U_{0,0}\cup U_{1,1}$, but $(0,0,0,...)\in U_{0,0}\cup U_{1,1}$.  Notice also that $(0,0,0,...)\not\in U_{1,1}$, so $U_{0,0}\cup U_{1,1}\not=U_{1,1}$.

Indeed, we need to show that any open set in the product topology can be written as a union of the sets $U_{y_1, ..., y_n}$, which I will call cylinder sets.  As you know, open sets in the product topology here are unions of  $\prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} V_i$ where each $V_i\subset \{0,1\}$ and where the set $I=\{i\in \mathbb{N} : V_i\not=\{0,1\}\}$ is finite.  Here, this means that we need to be able to, given $J\subset \mathbb{N}$ with $|J|<\infty$, and a function $f:J\rightarrow \{0,1\}$, write the collection $V=\{x \in X: x_j=f(j), \ \forall j\in J\}$ as a union of cylinder sets.

That is, we need to find finite sequences $X_1, ..., X_k$ such that $V=\cup_{m=1}^k U_{X_m}$.  Here, I'm thinking of a sequence $X_m= x_{m, 1}, x_{m, 2}, ..., x_{m, n_m}$, and $$U_{X_m}=U_{x_{m, 1},\ \ x_{m, 2} \ \ , ..., x_{m, n_m}}\ \ $$

So, using the notation from above, if $J=\{1,2, ..., n\}$, then $V=U_{f(1), f(2), ..., f(n)}$ is trivial!  However, what if $J$ is more complicated, like if $J=\{4,5,6, 101,102, 103\}$?

I hope that this will get you started!

Comment: Thank you. I now understand how the union of those cylinder sets work. But I am not sure, if I get everything right in the second part of your answer. Why is the collection $I=\{i\in\mathbb{N}: V_i\neq\{0,1\}\}$ finite? Does this mean there are only finite sets $V_i$ with $V_i=\{0,1\}$, so infinite sets just contain $0$ or $1$ and not both numbers. What does that mean for the product $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} V_i$? That there are only finite indeces which can have two possible assignments. (Just like in the set $U_0\cup U_1$ where the first index can be 0 or 1)

Comment: @MrTopology: You have it backwards. There are only finitely many indices $i$ such that $V_i=\{0\}$ or $V_i=\{1\}$; for all of the other indices, $V_i=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Ah, I see. And the function $f$ now provides to those sets (which are a finite amount) an unique value (0 or 1). Unfortunatly I am not a native speaker. Could you please explain what is meant by "collection" in the mathematical context.

Comment: I'm using the word collection to mean 'set,' which I changed in the answer.   I added a more explicit description of how you might want to write an open set in the product topology as a union of cylinder sets.  Unfortunately, this involved sequences of sequences, which makes indexing sort of a mess...