# What are the cylinder sets in the Cantor space?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

Let $\{0,1\}^\omega$ be the Cantor space. I know that its elements are infinite sequences of binary digits (e.g. $0,1,0,1,0,...$)

What are the cylinder sets in the Cantor space $\{0,1\}^\omega$? Are they the clopen sets?

If so, what is their exact definition?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772598/75923) and its answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the cylinder sets are the basic open subsets, so those open sets of the form $\prod_n O_n$ where all $O_n = \{0,1\}$ except for some $n \in F$, where $F \subset \omega$ is finite, for which $O_n$ we have a proper open subset. 
In $\{0,1\}$ we only can choose $\{0\}$ or $\{1\}$ for those (if we have a non-empty open set of course).

So these are exactly all infinite sequences that agree with those finitely many choices of $0$ or $1$ on a finite set $F$ of indices. So it's determined by a choice of such a finite set $F \subset \omega$ and a word $w$ from $\{0,1\}$ of length $|F|$.

These cylinder sets are indeed clopen sets, but finite unions of them are also open (and not always cylinder sets), and of course all clopen subsets are finite unions of them.

Comment: "So these are exactly all infinite sequences that agree with those finitely many choices of 0 or 1 on a finite set F of indices" Could you please give an example using a sequence of binary digits? Also, is it correct to say that an ordinary clopen set is just a finite union of cylinder sets?

Comment: @student e.g. All  binary sequences $(x_n)$ that obey $x_3=0=x_5$ and $x_6=1$, to name an example. And all clopen sets are finite unions of such sets as a compactness argument shows.